# Display Only Two Days in week In jQuery UI Date Picker

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to only show `Monday`s and `Thursdays` in jQuery UI calendar. I am able to enable only `Monday`s  but not sure how to add `Thursdays` to the return list as well?
Can u also let me know how to not display other days(instead of rendering disabled button)?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var day = date.getDay();
      return [(day == 1)];
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
Date:
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add condition for Thursday too. Use css to if you want to hide other days

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      const day = date.getDay();
      const enable=(day === 1||day===4);
      return [enable,enable?'':'hide'];
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<style>
.hide{
     visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
Date:
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```